# joomla article editor not working

Tags: joomla, editor

I have been developing a new version of my Joomla website on a test server. When I copy the database over to the live site I can't edit any of my articles. When I click on an article to edit it, I get a white screen with just fields for the title, category, section and two or three others, but no content field. there is also no formatting on the page. I am pretty sure I have copied across all the new files I added, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

The website is working fine otherwise, and I have tried using different editors and no editor at all.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

If you moved the site manually, there are all kinds of things that can go wrong. Here is what I would do -

1. Install Akeeba Backup on the development site - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606
2. Take a full backup, then upload the zip file to your server
3. Install using the Akeeba wizard

This will insure that you didn't miss anything and any necessary config settings are updated - temp and log files generally reside in a different location for one. It wouldn't hurt to confirm the directory permissions in the Joomla admin, but chance are it will work properly once you install with Akeeba.

Comment: Hi Brent, Thanks very much for your answer. I managed to solve the problem by copying all the site files from the test server to the live server.

Comment: Wow, that is the hard way! Check out Akeeba, it's free and works like a charm. I've moved dozens of site of all sizes without a single problem. Good luck!